# Cannot generate initramfs supports encrypted root

Tags: boot, kernel, encryption

I recently reinstalled my laptop which hdd I partitioned as a boot and an encrypted root, the same as before.
To save time on drivers, I copied initrd.img from previous installation. Everything was fine until I installed new kernel from kernel-ppa.
The newly generated initrd.img does not ask for passphrase at all. It just waits for root device to be populated which is sure not to happen until timeout and falls back to busybox.

How to fix this? I have cryptsetup installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a few hours to read through initrd process and found that new ramdisk does not contain conf/conf.d/cryptroot file which is generated from /etc/crypttab. So the root cause is that I forgot to fix /etc/crypttab according to new environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues just recently.
My is advice is re-install the OS and since you have your previous install, only copy what is needed, say files etc **leave out the drivers**. **I would do away with the total encryption too as I was advised to**. Things go fine with any new updates

Comment: Reinstall is the last option to me. Backup and restore just took so long....

Comment: If re-install saves you a lot of trouble then I advice you take it. Recovery from busybox will require you getting help from a real pro and it would definitely take very long

Comment: The old kernel is still working. So not too worry. And I'd like to the why since everything is following standard procedure.